# Show latest content date from group content type

Tags: views, 9, group

I've a group type vendor with following groups:

- V1
- V2
- V3

Each group is associated with content type notes as shown below:

Notes (Content Type) with nodes associated with groups:

```
N1 (Group: V1)
N2 (Group: V1)
N3 (Group: V2)
N4 (Group: V2)
N5 (Group: V3)
```

So the relationship between them goes like this.

| Vendor (Group Type) |
| --- |

| Group V1 | Group V2 | Group V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | N3 | N5 |
| N2 | N4 | None |

Where N* are nodes of content type **Notes**

I want to create a view where following data should be displayed:

```
V1
    Latest content update date
V2
    Latest content update date
```

But I do not want all the contents update date listed. When I use grid layout I can group the content as per associated group but the output contains all the last updated date for all contents. I want to limit the output only to last 2-3 contents.

Example:

Views -> Grid Layout -> Group by group title -> Number of columns per row -> 2

Output:

```
V1

N1 last update date     N2 last update date

V2

N3 last update date     N4 last update date
```

Expected output:

```
V1

N1 last update date

V2

N3 last update date
```

Comment: This can't be done through one Views, you have to create as many displays as you have types to be able to show only the latest one in the results, then display them one after the other in your theme region and use CSS to make them look like they are all part of the same block.

Comment: @prkos But how to relate them with each other. For e.g I've one views with Group title and other with group content last update date and create relationship with them. I've tried it with Views attachment but there is no relationship available for Group Title.

Comment: I forgot how Groups track content, is it through an Entity Reference Field? Even if it isn't there is probably a feature in Views that enables showing related info. The Group and its content is shown in the same Views, usually through a Relationship for the ER field. One of your Views can be content Views for N1 and N2, show Group field (through a Relationship if necessary), latest change date field, and in pager limit to show only 1 result. Similarly create another Block for N3 and N4, and the third Block for N5.

Comment: We have thousands of content and they are created dynamically as per requirements. So creating separate views for each of them is not feasible.

Comment: I might have misunderstood, do you have one Notes Content Type? I understood those are different types, not different nodes of the same type.

Comment: If your Ns are all nodes of the same type you have to start with Group Views. You'll need 3 different Views, one for each Group. Add the reverse Relationship for the node-to-group connection, then you will be able to add the Title field with that Relationship applied to get the Title of the Node instead of Group. Set in pager to show only one result, Sort by post date of course.

Comment: @prkos I've updated the question to explain relationship between content type, nodes and group. Also, groups are dynamic. Only constant are Content type and Group Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a some research and hit and trial I'm able to configure views output as per requirements with [Views merge row](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) module. Below are the steps I've followed:

1. Install Views Merge Row module.
2. Create a Views with group content type.
3. Select Format -> Card
4. Add fields:

   - Group Title
   - Content Changed on (relationship content)

3. In card settings Select "Group Field 1" as a Group Title.
4. Now under views Advance-settings Select "Merge rows"
5. Under Merge row settings select following configuration:

| Field | Merge Option |
| --- | --- |
| Group Title | Use Values of this field as a filter |
| Content Changed | Use First Value of this Field |

6. Sort -> Ascending